# How can I call a generator function inside mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

This is really a simple JS question; I'm sure the problem is one of scope. I want to do something like this, but this is incorrect syntax.

Basically, I want an event in my component to dispatch a different action each time the event happens. This whole approach may be wrong in which case I would like to know how this should be done.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    function* getNextSection() {
      yield dispatch(local_actions.general)
      yield dispatch(local_actions.fixbugs)
      yield dispatch(local_actions.resumefinish)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. The following code works:

```
const action1 => ({ type: 'action1' })
const action2 => ({ type: 'action2' })

function* actionGenerator() {
  yield action1()
  yield action2()
}

// A generator returns an iterator,
// it has to be stored in a variable
const actionIterator = actionGenerator()

const myAction = () => actionIterator.next().value

connect(mapStatetoProps, {
  myAction
})(MyComponent)
```

Then you can use it like:

```
this.props.myAction() // action1
this.props.myAction() // action2
```